# Is it possible passing directive to the event handler in angular?

Tags: angular

Is it OK in angular to do this:

```
//template file
<input *ngFor="let elem in elements" [myDirective]="elem" 
      (keyup.enter)="onEnter(myDirective)">

//.ts file
onEnter(dir: MyDirective){
   //access myDirective instanse here
}
```

I know I can do this by @ViewChildren but I want to ensure is it OK to pass directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your directive, make sure you set `exportAs`:

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[myDirective]',
 exportAs: 'myDirective'
})
```

Then, you can get a reference to it in the template:

```
<input *ngFor="let elem in elements" [myDirective]="elem" #test="myDirective"
  (keyup.enter)="onEnter(test)">
```

Here I've called it `test`, but you can call it whatever you want